# Send mails with PHP change From Address?

Tags: php, email

When I send a message with PHP the recipients gets a from address such as this one:

```
user123@p3nlhg147.shr.prod.phx3.secureserver.net
```

How can I use my custom email address like `info@mydomain.com` as sender address?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Part of the mail function is the ability to include headers.

You should send a From header, like so:

```
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: I don't understand something! I mean, you can basically put any address as from? Isn't this kinda insecure? I thought that I would only be able to link it with addresses from my domain.

Comment: @Liso22 Email is not secure.  Yes, you can put anything here. Read more: http://searchsecurity.techtarget.com/definition/email-spoofing  Most systems are advanced enough to detect this (i.e. GMail)

Answer (score 3):

If you mean how to change the field `From`, use this snippet from the [official doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php):

```
<?php
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```